# How is argument from function passed as a class ctor value

Tags: c++, seastar

In the code below, how is `max_dishes_on_table` being used in `seastar::coroutine::experimental::generator`? It is not referenced anywhere, or passed anywhere. And yet, it is used by the generator.

```
seastar::coroutine::experimental::generator<Dish, seastar::circular_buffer>
make_dishes(coroutine::experimental::buffer_size_t max_dishes_on_table,
            Ingredients&& ingredients) {
    while (ingredients) {
        auto some_ingredients = ingredients.alloc();
        auto preprocessed = co_await prepare_ingredients(std::move(some_ingredients));
        co_yield co_await cook_a_dish(std::move(preprocessed));
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you determining that it is used?

Comment: @user17732522, From the docs: "Please note, despite that this parameter is not referenced by the coroutine's body, it is actually passed to the generator's promise constructor, which in turn creates the buffer,"
Link to docs: https://github.com/scylladb/seastar/blob/master/doc/tutorial.md

Comment: @DeborahC I see what you mean now. Coroutines are simply specified to construct the promise object as if from the coroutine parameters, see https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.coroutine#5.7. But you don't need the `max_dishes_on_table` name for that. It has no relevance.

Comment: @user17732522 the name is irrlevant. The type must be there. But that type isn't references anywhere.

Comment: @DeborahC It is automatic as specified in the link to the standard draft above.

Comment: @user17732522 How does that work?

Comment: @DeborahC The C++ language specification above says (roughly) that when calling a coroutine, the promise object for the coroutine is constructed as if the parameters of the coroutine would be listed as constructor arguments, assuming that overload resolution for the constructor call would succeed. So the compiler will have to implement the coroutine function to behave like that.

Comment: @user17732522 this is the ctor: "generator(size_t buffer_capacity,
              handle_type coro,
              promise_type* promise) noexcept"
How this ^^^ can be assembled from this: make_dishes(coroutine::experimental::buffer_size_t max_dishes_on_table,
            Ingredients&& ingredients

Comment: @DeborahC That's not the promise type. The promise type is aliased [here](https://github.com/scylladb/seastar/blob/master/include/seastar/coroutine/generator.hh#L315) and it has a variadic constructor [here](https://github.com/scylladb/seastar/blob/master/include/seastar/coroutine/generator.hh#L161).

Comment: @user17732522 thanks, that I can understand now. But how then, the generator got constructed when clearly there isn't correct number nor type of args  supplied?

Comment: @DeborahC It is constructed [here](https://github.com/scylladb/seastar/blob/master/include/seastar/coroutine/generator.hh#L508) or [here](https://github.com/scylladb/seastar/blob/master/include/seastar/coroutine/generator.hh#L525). A coroutine itself doesn't inherently construct any object of its return type. That's the job of `promise_type::get_return_object`.

Comment: @user17732522 Thank you, really appreciate your help in beginning to understanding it. It seems to me that coroutines are very, very convoluted and at the current moment working with them is just painfull...

Comment: @DeborahC They are specified to be as flexible as possible for library authors. A user should just use a library like the one you are asking about and follow its usage instructions. The implementation details aren't really relevant. At least that seems to be the intention to me.

Comment: @user17732522 yes, I agree with you.

Comment: @user17732522 Once again, thank you for your help.